# How to make SVG stroke with visible overflow on Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, svg, stroke

Maybe it's a bug, but check this out. https://codepen.io/Firsh/pen/LegGQq

```css
/* 
Only these work:*/
/*
symbol{ overflow: visible; }
*/

/*
#circle-symbol{ overflow:visible; }
*/

/* NO matter how I target it, it doesn't work... */
.product symbol, svg symbol, .definitions symbol {
    overflow: visible;
}

.my-circle{
    overflow: visible;
    fill:red;
    stroke-width:15px;
    stroke:#000;
}
.definitions{
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<br>This is cut off on Firefox only:<br><br>
<div class="product">
  
  <svg viewBox="0 0 90 90" width="90" height="90" class="my-circle" style="">
    <use xlink:href="#circle-symbol"></use>
  </svg>
  
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="definitions">
    <defs>
      <symbol id="circle-symbol" viewBox="0 0 90 90">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M76.85,13.2C85.616,21.967,90,32.567,90,45c0,12.434-4.384,23.017-13.15,31.75  C68.05,85.583,57.434,90,45,90c-12.367,0-22.967-4.417-31.8-13.25C4.4,68.017,0,57.434,0,45c0-12.433,4.4-23.033,13.2-31.8  C22.033,4.4,32.633,0,45,0C57.434,0,68.05,4.4,76.85,13.2z"></path>
      </symbol>
    </defs>
  </svg>

</div>

<br>This is how it should look like (Chrome, Edge):<br>
<img src="https://i.snag.gy/cxM306.jpg" width="109" height="108" />
```

I've found that when my CSS selector is direct, it works. Otherwise, no matter how I try to qualify symbol to add the visible overflow property, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox implements SVG 2 `<use>` elements. In SVG 2 `<use>` selectors [must not cross the shadow document boundary](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#UseStyleInheritance) i.e. you can't point part of the CSS selector to the  (or its parents) and the other part to the `<use>` reference.

Chrome, Safari and Edge will likely change to match Firefox at some point.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this problem, this solved it for me

```
svg, symbol { overflow: visible; }
```

[Updated codepen here](https://codepen.io/lunelson/pen/mGaMzd?editors=0100)